# Sum of two chars in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, char

I am learning Kotlin and I'd like to know why am I able to subtract between two Char variables in Kotlin, but their sum presents this error:

```
    >>> 'A' + 'B'
error: the character literal does not conform to the expected type Int
'A' + 'B'
      ^

>>> 'A' - 'B'
res40: kotlin.Int = -1
>>>
```

I am aware this is a really basic issue...

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your code aswell?

Comment: @Amy I posted it within my post. It's in the command line.

Comment: `Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "A" + "B", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()` shows a toast of "AB", is this the output you're expecting?

Comment: No, I just want to understand why is it presenting that error... Please try to type it in your command line.

Comment: The `-` between 2 `Char`s is defined as how far away they are in the ASCII table, that returns an integer, and that's an operation one can sensibly do. Conversely the sum has a much less clear meaning, if you want to find a character which is `n` elements away on the ASCII table, then do `A + n` where n is an Int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-char/plus.html) this is not possible if the operation is done just relying on Kotlin's type inference.
'A' + 'B' can be written as 'A'.plus('B'), but the addition operator (.plus) for Char only accepts Int in the second parcel.

One way to make this operation work would be 'A' + 'B'.toInt(), but it still wouldn't print a legal answer, because the sum of the values 'A' = 65 and 'B' = 66 doesn't exist in the ASCII table.